# XML mapping service

Tags: xml, spring, web-services

I need help with creating client.
I got some example of request and I should make client for that:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
xmlns:rtdm="http://www.test.com/xml/schema/test-svcs/rtdm-1.1">
<soapenv:Header />
<soapenv:Body>
    <rtdm:Event name="Call">
        <rtdm:Header>
            <!--Optional: -->
            <rtdm:Identity>TEST</rtdm:Identity>
            <rtdm:ClientTimeZoneID>EUROPE/BELGRADE</rtdm:ClientTimeZoneID>
        </rtdm:Header>
        <rtdm:Body>
            <rtdm:Data name="CLIENTID">
                <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level -->
                <rtdm:String>
                    <!--Optional: -->
                    <rtdm:Val>16</rtdm:Val>
                </rtdm:String>
            </rtdm:Data>
            <rtdm:Data name="AGENT_ID">
                <!--You have a CHOICE of the next 2 items at this level -->
                <rtdm:String>
                    <!--Optional: -->
                    <rtdm:Val>10</rtdm:Val>
                </rtdm:String>
            </rtdm:Data>
            <rtdm:Data name="balance">
                <rtdm:Float>
                    <rtdm:Val>100</rtdm:Val>
                </rtdm:Float>
            </rtdm:Data>
            </rtdm:Body>
    </rtdm:Event>
</soapenv:Body>
```

So far I have made class that have:

```
@XmlElement(name = "Header", namespace = "http://www.test.com/xml/schema/test-svcs/rtdm-1.1")
private HeaderType header;

@XmlElement(name = "Body", namespace = "http://www.test.com/xml/schema/test-svcs/rtdm-1.1")
private BodyType body;
```

And I start making BodyType class:

```
@XmlElement(name = "CLIENTID", namespace = "http://www.test.com/xml/schema/test-svcs/rtdm-1.1")
private String clientId;

@XmlElement(name = "AGENT_ID", namespace = "http://www.test.com/xml/schema/test-svcs/rtdm-1.1")
private String agentId;

@XmlElement(name = "balance", namespace = "http://www.test.com/xml/schema/test-svcs/rtdm-1.1")
private Double accountBalance;
```

But I am not sure how to make this from example:

```
<rtdm:Data name="CLIENTID">
    <rtdm:String>
            <rtdm:Val>16</rtdm:Val>
    </rtdm:String>
</rtdm:Data>

<rtdm:Data name="AGENTID">
    <rtdm:String>
        <rtdm:Val>10</rtdm:Val>
    </rtdm:String>
</rtdm:Data>
.....
```

Is this some list of Data class and how to make property name=ClientID, name=AGENTID ...
And how to generate to have this effect inside of that class:

```
<rtdm:String>
            <rtdm:Val>16</rtdm:Val>
    </rtdm:String>
```

This is wsdl:

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<definitions name="TEST"
             xmlns="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/"
             targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/xml/schema/test-svcs/rmdt-1.1/wsdl/"
             xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/xml/schema/test-svcs/rmdt-1.1/wsdl/"
             xmlns:typesns="http://www.test.com/xml/schema/test-svcs/rmdt-1.1"
             xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/">

   <types>
      <schema xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
              targetNamespace="http://www.test.com/xml/schema/test-svcs/rmdt-1.1"
              xmlns:tns="http://www.test.com/xml/schema/test-svcs/rmdt-1.1"
              elementFormDefault="qualified">

         <simpleType name="NameType">
          <annotation>
            <documentation>
                Defines a standard format for names that include spaces.
                e.g. file names
            </documentation>
          </annotation>
          <restriction base="normalizedString">
            <maxLength value="255" />
            <pattern
                value="[^\\/:\*\?&quot;&lt;&gt;\|@&amp;#&apos;~`\[\]\{\}]*" />
          </restriction>
         </simpleType>

         <simpleType name="DataTypes">
           <annotation>
            <documentation>Primitive data types supported </documentation>
           </annotation>
           <restriction base="normalizedString">
            <enumeration value="Int" />
            <enumeration value="Boolean" />
            <enumeration value="Float" />
            <enumeration value="DateTime" />
            <enumeration value="String" />
            <enumeration value="Table" />
           </restriction>
         </simpleType>

         <element name="String">
            <complexType>
               <sequence>
                  <element name="Val" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
               </sequence>
            </complexType>
         </element>

         <element name="StringArray">
            <complexType>
               <sequence>
                  <element name="Val" minOccurs="0">
                     <complexType>
                        <sequence>
                           <element name="Item" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                        </sequence>
                     </complexType>
                  </element>
               </sequence>
            </complexType>
         </element>

         <element name="Int">
            <complexType>
               <sequence>
                  <element name="Val" type="long" minOccurs="0"/>
               </sequence>
            </complexType>
         </element>
         <element name="IntArray">
            <complexType>
               <sequence>
                  <element name="Val" minOccurs="0">
                     <complexType>
                        <sequence>
                           <element name="Item" type="long" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                        </sequence>
                     </complexType>
                  </element>
               </sequence>
            </complexType>
         </element>

         <element name="Float">
            <complexType>
               <sequence>
                  <element name="Val" type="double" minOccurs="0"/>
               </sequence>
            </complexType>
         </element>
         <element name="FloatArray">
            <complexType>
               <sequence>
                  <element name="Val" minOccurs="0">
                     <complexType>
                        <sequence>
                           <element name="Item" type="double" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                        </sequence>
                     </complexType>
                  </element>
               </sequence>
            </complexType>
         </element>

         <element name="Boolean">
            <complexType>
               <sequence>
                   <element name="Val" type="boolean" minOccurs="0"/>
               </sequence>
            </complexType>
         </element>
         <element name="BooleanArray">
            <complexType>
               <sequence>
                  <element name="Val" minOccurs="0">
                     <complexType>
                        <sequence>
                           <element name="Item" type="boolean" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                        </sequence>
                     </complexType>
                  </element>
               </sequence>
            </complexType>
         </element>

         <element name="DateTime">
            <complexType>
               <sequence>
                  <element name="Val" type="dateTime" minOccurs="0"/>
               </sequence>
            </complexType>
         </element>
         <element name="DateTimeArray">
            <complexType>
               <sequence>
                  <element name="Val" minOccurs="0">
                     <complexType>
                        <sequence>
                           <element name="Item" type="dateTime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
                        </sequence>
                     </complexType>
                  </element>
               </sequence>
            </complexType>
         </element>

         <complexType name="TableDataType">
           <annotation>
              <documentation>
                Only one of the following sequenced elements should be
                included with element TableType.Row.Col below. This schema 
                does not make this constraint visible for reasons previously 
                noted.
              </documentation>
            </annotation>
          <sequence>
            <element ref="tns:String" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <element ref="tns:Int" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <element ref="tns:Float" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <element ref="tns:Boolean" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
            <element ref="tns:DateTime" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="1" />
          </sequence>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="TableColumnType">
          <attribute name="name" type="tns:NameType" use="required" />
          <attribute name="type" type="tns:DataTypes" use="required" />
        </complexType>

        <complexType name="TableRowType">
           <sequence>
            <!-- A row, if it exists at all, must have at least 1 Col element -->
            <element name="Col" type="tns:TableDataType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
          </sequence>
        </complexType>
        <complexType name="TableType">
          <sequence>
            <!--  Order of Columns must match order of data in Rows
                  Table may be completely empty to start, hence minOccurs 0
            -->
            <element name="Column" type="tns:TableColumnType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
            <element name="Row" type="tns:TableRowType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" />
          </sequence>
        </complexType>

         <element name="Table">
            <complexType>
              <sequence>
                <element name="Val" type="tns:TableType" minOccurs="0" />
              </sequence>
            </complexType>
         </element> 

        <element name="TableArray">
             <complexType>
               <sequence>
                  <element name="Val" minOccurs="0">
                    <complexType>
                        <sequence>
                            <element name="Item" type="tns:TableType" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded" nillable="true" />
                        </sequence>
                    </complexType>
                  </element>
              </sequence>
             </complexType>
        </element>

         <annotation>
            <documentation>
            Input-Type-Mapping:
            [CLIENTID:String],
            [AGENTID:String],
            [BALANCE:Float]
            </documentation>
         </annotation>
         <complexType name="DataItemType">
            <choice>
               <element ref="tns:String"/>
               <element ref="tns:Float"/>
            </choice>
            <attribute name="name" use="required">
               <simpleType>
                  <restriction base="string">
                     <enumeration value="CLIENTID"/>
                     <enumeration value="AGENTID"/>
                     <enumeration value="BALANCE"/>
                  </restriction>
               </simpleType>
            </attribute>
         </complexType>

         <annotation>
            <documentation>
            Output-Type-Mapping:
            [CLIENTID:String],
            [AGENTID:Float],
            [DESCRIPTION:StringArray]
            </documentation>
         </annotation>
         <complexType name="DataItemResponseType">
            <choice>
               <element ref="tns:String"/>
               <element ref="tns:Float"/>
               <element ref="tns:StringArray"/>
            </choice>
            <attribute name="name" use="required">
               <simpleType>
                  <restriction base="string">
                     <enumeration value="CLIENTID"/>
                     <enumeration value="AGENTID"/>
                     <enumeration value="DESCRIPTION"/>
                  </restriction>
               </simpleType>
            </attribute>
         </complexType>

         <complexType name="HeaderType">
            <sequence>
               <element name="Identity" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
               <element name="ClientTimeZoneID" type="normalizedString" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
            </sequence>
         </complexType>

         <complexType name="HeaderResponseType">
            <sequence>
               <element name="CorrelationId" type="string" minOccurs="0"/>
               <element name="StartTime" type="string"/>
               <element name="CompletionTime" type="string"/>
            </sequence>
         </complexType>

         <complexType name="BodyType">
            <sequence>
               <element name="Data" type="tns:DataItemType" minOccurs="9" maxOccurs="9"/>
            </sequence>
         </complexType>

         <complexType name="BodyResponseType">
            <sequence>
               <element name="Data" type="tns:DataItemResponseType" minOccurs="15" maxOccurs="15"/>
            </sequence>
         </complexType>

         <complexType name="EventType">
            <sequence>
               <element name="Header" type="tns:HeaderType" minOccurs="1" maxOccurs="1"/>
               <element name="Body" type="tns:BodyType"/>
            </sequence>
            <attribute name="name" type="string" use="required" fixed="test"/>
         </complexType>

         <complexType name="EventResponseType">
            <sequence>
               <element name="Header" type="tns:HeaderResponseType"/>
               <element name="Body" type="tns:BodyResponseType"/>
            </sequence>
            <attribute name="name" type="string" use="required" fixed="test"/>
         </complexType>

         <element name="Event" type="tns:EventType"/>
         <element name="EventResponse" type="tns:EventResponseType"/>

         <element name="FaultException" type="tns:FaultException"/>
         <complexType name="FaultException">
            <sequence>
               <element name="ExceptionMessage" type="string" minOccurs="0" maxOccurs="unbounded"/>
            </sequence>
         </complexType>
      </schema>
   </types>

   <message name="eventRequest">
      <part name="parameters" element="typesns:Event"/>
   </message>
   <message name="eventResponse">
      <part name="parameters" element="typesns:EventResponse"/>
   </message>
   <message name="FaultException">
      <part name="detail" element="typesns:FaultException"/>
   </message>

   <portType name="EventPortType">
      <operation name="Event">
         <input message="tns:eventRequest"/>
         <output message="tns:eventResponse"/>
         <fault name="fault" message="tns:FaultException"/>
      </operation>
   </portType>

   <binding name="EventSoapBinding" type="tns:EventPortType">
      <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" style="document"/>
      <operation name="Event">
         <soap:operation soapAction=""/>
         <input>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </input>
         <output>
            <soap:body use="literal"/>
         </output>
         <fault name="fault">
            <soap:fault name="fault" use="literal"/>
         </fault>
      </operation>
   </binding>


</definitions>
```

Comment: Simply don't... Ask for the contract (the xsd or wsdl) and use that to generate those classes, don't try to reverse engineer them from an existing xml request.

Comment: I have added wsdl in my post

Comment: but i still don't know how to get this effect:
    <rtdm:Data name="AGENTID">
    <rtdm:String>
        <rtdm:Val>10</rtdm:Val>
    </rtdm:String>
</rtdm:Data>

Comment: Use the contract to generate your classes using the JAXB tooling... Don't try to do it by hand. Those classes are all you need, JAXB will then take care of the rest...